# How do I repeat events in an ICS file every x seconds?

Tags: calendar, icalendar, macos-sierra

I'm trying to set up calendar events in macOS Sierra's Calendar that repeat every 2,551,440 seconds (which happens to be the synodic period of the Moon). This system uses the ICS specification.

Ultimately, I want a calendar that provides the Moon rise and set times for my location, and it also needs to list the Lunar phase (e.g. Full Moon, New Moon, etc.). I have found plenty of examples on the Internet where people have manually created the events, but that's incredibly tedious (one event per day for years!), and they're based on different time zones (and so are of no use to me).

I have seen from the ICS specifications that the file format itself supports events that recur every x seconds. I exported an event as an ICS file (from Calendar), and then edited the ICS file in a text editor, but I must've got the code wrong, as it didn't re-import into macOS Calendar with the correct repeat interval. Instead, it imported a single event with no repetition. It's also possible that I got the code right, but Calendar discarded it upon import...

Can someone please explain how to go about doing this?

I found [the RRULE Generator](https://www.textmagic.com/free-tools/rrule-generator), but that only supports hourly intervals, not seconds, and so is not precise enough for my needs.

I considered running a bash script to generate the event (which would run as a cron job every 2,551,440 seconds), but that would only give a month's notice. I'd prefer to have it set up indefinitely.

Another option may be to write a script in Python to create individual ICS event files; this would also be tedious...

I understand that this can't be done in Calendar directly; the solution will most likely be manually editing each ICS file to set up the recurrence correctly, and then importing them into Calendar... I just don't know how...

...or is there a calendar application somewhere out there that lets you set up events that recur every x seconds? If so, I could create the event in that, export it and then import it into Calendar...

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured this one out.

1. Apple Calendar, Google Calendar, and pretty much all calendar applications don't support events that repeat every x seconds. The ICS format itself does, just not the programs.
2. The Moon is in an inclined orbit, so this is an inappropriate solution for what I wanted anyway.
3. The [US Navy has an API](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/api.php) that publishes rise/set and phase data for the Moon. I saved the responses from this page (a JSON file), and did some Python code to extract the required data, and then made a Python script to create the separate .ICS files for each event (one event per Moonrise) (i.e. **not** one event that repeats every x seconds). I then imported those ICS files into macOS Calendar.

Hope this helps someone else who needs to deal with a similar situation in future...